# In-memory RAM disk for PCF cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, rocksdb

I have to store some data in RocksDB in a PCF environment where I have only limited disc but ~10Gigs of main memory available. So, I would like to leverage RAM disk for that. Is there any provision in PCF to do that? Can leverage a custom sidecar buildpack?

P.S.: I am aware of whole cattle vs Pet. This is more like a local cache for improving performance, I have state store elsewhere. So I am okay with the ephemeral nature of CF containers and data-written-to-disk-being-lost frequently/occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do anything in your application container for which you have permission (`cf ssh` is a good way to test if you have permission), but you're not going to be able to mount file systems as you won't have permission to do that. Way back, you could mount fuse file systems, but even that is restricted in current versions of CF.

Cloud Foundry has a mechanism through which users can mount file systems. It's called [Volume Services](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/using-vol-services.html). There is support for mounting NFS & SMB volumes, but I've not seen support for mounting a RAM disk.

If you need more disk space than can be requested with `cf push -k` then, a volume service is likely what you want. Not only will it give you more space, it will offer persistent data storage.

Comment: Can I mount RAM using an intermediate buildpack (in supply) 
`sudo mount -t tmpfs -o rw,size=2G tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk`

Comment: The buildpack doesn't have elevated permissions, it has the same restrictions and isn't allowed to mount anything. Mounting has to happen outside of the container on the Cell and be overlayed onto the container, which is what volume services does.